# Elasticsearch | Match multiple phrases

Tags: elasticsearch, match, dsl, querydsl

Im trying to create a query that will find all statuses that contain either  #breakingbad OR  "breaking bad"

here is what i have so far , but its obviously wrong according to sense:

```
{
   "query": {

      "match": {

         "_all": {

            "query": "breaking bad",
            "type": "phrase"
         }
      },
      "match": {
         "_all": {
             "query": "#breakingbad",
             "type": "phrase"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried embedding your match queries in a bool query?

Answer (score 3):

**ANSWER:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": {
                            "query": "breaking bad",
                            "type": "phrase"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "message": "#poznasty"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

why not use multi_match

```
{
    "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "fields" : ["name", "description"],
            "query" : "breaking bad",
            "type" : "phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}

MultiMatchQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query,
    "name", "description").type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);
```

Comment: As far as I know, `mutli_match` will look amongst multiple fields. Whereas what the author of the issue is asking is to look for multiple possible phrases (OR) in a single field.